# Typescript importing types from a library

Tags: typescript, firebase

How can we import types from a file in typescript?

This is what I am doing,

I have a main file

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as util from "util";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import Storage from "./{some-location}"

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert("./.keys/admin.keys.json"),
});

const firestore = admin.firestore();

const context = {
  functions: functions,
  Storage: new Storage(admin) 
};
```

Here, I am passing `admin` to `new Storage(admin)`

```
class Storage {
    constructor (admin) {
        const storage = admin.storage();
    }
}
```

In storage, I want to declare type for `admin` or typescript is complaining that `admin` type is any.

How can fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

'admin' is a namespace, you shouldn't be passing it to your constructor.

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

class Storage {
  constructor () {
    const storage = admin.storage();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`admin` isn't a variable you can pass around.  If you just need the same `admin` from `firebase-admin` in all of your source files, just import it the same way from each one:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
```

The import is essentially global to your entire node process.

Or perhaps you are actually thinking to pass around an initialized [App](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.app.App) object?  You can pass an App to the [Storage constructor](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.storage).

```
const app = admin.initializeApp(...);
const context = {
  functions: functions,
  Storage: new Storage(app) 
};

class Storage {
    constructor (app) {
        const storage = admin.storage(app);
    }
}
```

The [Firestore constructor](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore) works the same way.  Without an argument it takes the global default, but you can pass the App to be explicit.